# can i skip "cordova platform add android / ios" if im going to build it online via phonegap build?

Tags: cordova

good day! i have been developing web and desktop apps for sometime now primarily using html/css/js/php or androidstudio/xcode, but iam very new to phonegap. i started creating my phonegap from a blank/empty project template using the gui phonegap desktop app, added some html/js/css with ionic framework. it work fine on the phonegap server. i then uploaded and built it using online (free 50mb) phonegap build service and was able to build an apk from it. i never used the phonegap/cordova cli or commands in my project.

upon reading more of the phonegap docs on these pass few days, i recently encounter a step i haven't done before --"cordova platform add android","cordova prepare android". i tested it and it added directories to my platform folder.  do i really need these platform folders? it has made my folder size very big (50+mb). without those folders my app is just 30+mb. do i really need them? i no longer can upload my project zip to online build service since it is already over the limit of a free account. can i go without adding the platform folders?

thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using PhoneGap Build, you specify the platforms for which you are building in `config.xml`. The commands you are referring to apply to local building, not building with PGB.

PGB and the CLI can be used together, so if you want to build locally, you can. That said, when you upload to PGB, you should never upload `platforms/` or `plugins/`, since doing so may confuse the building process (and is a waste of bandwidth anyway).

Comment: oh. so i can safety delete my platforms/ and plugins/ before i zip my project and upload it to online PGB?

Comment: Yes, assuming you won't build locally. (If the latter, you can just exclude the folders from the zip.)